# How to find all file extensions recursively from a directory?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

What command, or collection of commands, can I use to return all file extensions in a directory (including sub-directories)?

Right now, I'm using different combinations of `ls` and `grep`, but I can't find any scalable solution.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

How about this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's|.*\.||' | sort -u
```

Comment: find [this directory] (files) (matching any name with an extension) | use sed to substitute anything preceding a period with nothing | sort with unique flag

Comment: But this does'nt go into sub-directories.

Comment: @BhaskarChakradhar Yes it does. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: thank you, this is very useful, i'm using this on chromium source code directory and got thousands of file extensions, many of them are actually files without file extension, is there anyway to ignore all files without file extension?

Comment: This also gets all "dot files", like e.g. `.ctags`, which is usually not what you want.

Comment: Can I suggest changing the "   -name '*.*  '"     to  "-name '[^.]*.*'  as the former also picks up lots of "invisible" files such has temporary edits produced by xemacs?

Comment: @DevSolar to exclude dot files you can indicate you want at least one chat before the dot using the question mark, ``-name '?*.*'``.  Glob matching is less powerful than regex but much faster.

Answer (score 10):

list all extensions and their counts of current and all sub-directories

```
ls -1R | sed 's/[^\.]*//' | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 8):

```
find . -type f | sed 's|.*\.||' | sort -u
```

Also works on mac.

Comment: This solution doesn't ensure all files listed _have_ extensions, so files without them aren't fixed by sed and are treated _as_ extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Another one, similar to others but only uses two programs (find and awk)

`find ./ -type f -name "*\.*" -printf "%f\n" | awk -F . '!seen[$NF]++ {print $NF}'`

`-type f` restricts it to just files, not directories

`-name "*\.*"` ensures the filename has a `.` in it.

`-printf "%f\n"` prints just the filename, not the path to the filename.

`-F .` makes awk utilize a period as the field separator.

`$NF` is the last field, separated by periods.

`!seen[$NF]++` evaluates to true the first time an extension is encountered, and false every other time it is encountered.

`print $NF` prints the extension.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.*
do
  echo "${file##*.}
done
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -e 'Dir["**/*.*"].each{|x|puts x.split(".")[-1]}' | sort -u
```

Comment: For me using `MSYS2`, the pattern `"${file##*.}"` will only print the final part of extensions with two dots (for example it only prints `.gz` when the extension is `.tar.gz`). The pattern `"${file#*.}` prints every part of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution using find (that should even sort file extensions with embedded newlines correctly):

```
# [^.]: exclude dotfiles
find . -type f -name "[^.]*.*" -exec bash -c '
  printf "%s\000" "${@##*.}"
' argv0 '{}' + |
sort -uz | 
tr '\0' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Boooom another:

```
find * | awk -F . {'print $2'} | sort -u
```

Comment: `echo 'gniourf.tar.gz' | awk -F . {'print $2'}` gives `tar` and `echo 'one.two.three.pdf' | awk -F . {'print $2'}` gives `two`. Are you sure your approach is the good one?

Comment: I think the above solution is a simple solution, here I put another find . -type f -name "*.*" | awk -F. '!a[$NF]++{print $NF}' . I don't think with a simple commands you can't get every type of file. As you said before there are some problems parsing every row, so in this case I am sure is better to use some scripts in python, perl or similar in which you won't have this problem. Anyway I put a simple solution, if you now the extension of the files you can filter with a grep like | grep 'txt\|png\|pdf'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort -u
```

Update:
You are correct Matthew. Based on your comment, here is an updated version:

`ls -R1 | egrep -C 0 "[^\.]+\.[^\./:]+$" | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort -u`

Comment: This has two problems. First it only works for a flat directory, but misses subdirectories. Secondly, it includes all files without extensions in the output.

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), especially when it's useless.

Comment: You really should use ripgrep instead of egrep if you have time to install it first: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep and the updated command would be: `ls -R1 | rg -C 0 "[^\.]+\.[^\./:]+$" | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort -u` I get 10x at least improvement for huge folders.

Answer (score 0):

I was just quickly trying this as I was searching Google for a good answer. I am more Regex inclined than Bash, but this also works for subdirectories. I don't think includes files without extensions either:

`ls -R | egrep  '(\.\w+)$' -o | sort | uniq -c | sort -r`

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), especially when it's useless.