# List all files in a directory with a certain extension

Tags: bash, find

Let's say I want to list all `php` files in a directory including sub-directories, I can run this in bash:

`ls -l $(find. -name *.php -type f)`

The problem with this is that if there are no `php` files at all, the command that gets executed is `ls -l`, listing all files and directories, instead of none.

This is a problem, because I'm trying to get the combined size of all `php` files using

`ls -l $(find . -name *.php -type f) | awk '{s+=$5} END {print s}'`

which ends up returning the size of all entries in the event that there are no files matching the `*.php` pattern.

How can I guard against this event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all file extensions in directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998290/how-to-find-all-file-extensions-in-directory)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest you to firstly search the files and then perform the `ls -l` (or whatever else). For example like this:

```
find . -name "*php" -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

and then you can pipe the `awk` expression to make the addition.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was earlier doing `find . -name "*.php" -type f | xargs ls -l`, but facing the same problem.

Comment: Most of times it is not necessary to pipe `xargs` after `find`. The `exec` command gives you this utility. Note that it is necessary to use `{}` to refer to the file name found by `find`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to get the total size, you could say:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -printf "%s\n" | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: This is really cool as well. I didn't even know about the existence of `paste` and `bc`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, using `du`:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | du -c --files0-from=- | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

Comment: cool, i added -h to du and got the results in MB, just what i needed. thanks!