# Loop that should print file names returns empty lines instead

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I want to write a very basic script that return the file names of *txt files in the current directory. I wrote the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(ls *txt)

for FILE in $FILES
do
echo "$File"
done
```

The output of the script are 5 empty lines instead of the names of the 5 *txt files in the directoy.

Comment: I believe it should be `echo "$FILE"`, not `echo "$File"`. That would explain the  5 empty lines. Also see [List all files in a directory with a certain extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18823609/608639), [Loop through all the files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14505047/608639), [How do I perform an action on all files with a specific extension in subfolders?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50313/56041), [Recursively find files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25693638/608639), etc.

Comment: `File` is never set in your code, but apart from that your loop is severely broken anyway. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through all the files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505047/loop-through-all-the-files-with-a-specific-extension)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with this script:

1. `FILES` is not an array.
2. Never use the output of `ls` programmatically.
3. `FILE` and `File` are two different variables; names are case-sensitive.
4. All-uppercase names are reserved for use by the shell.

Your code should be

```
files=( *txt )  # ( *.txt ) would probably be cleaner
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Be aware, though, that depending on your shell settings, the assignment to `files` can have three different outcomes if there are no matching files:

1. `files` could contain a single element, literally `*txt` (the default)
2. `files` could be empty (with `nullglob` set)
3. The pattern match could produce an error (with `failglob` set)

Comment: Or just `for file in *txt; do ...`.