# Show and count all file extensions in directory (with subdirectories)

Tags: bash

I'm using command from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998290/how-to-find-all-file-extensions-in-directory) topic to view all file extensions in directory and all subdirectories.

`find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's|.*\.||' | sort -u`

How do I can count number of appearance for each extension?

Like:

`png: 140`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this, using [`uniq`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) with the `-c, --count` flag:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's|.*\.||' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Cheers mate! This is exactly what I wanted.